# CSS resets custom font in JavaFX

Tags: css, fonts, label, javafx-2

When I set a custom font for a Label in JavaFX 2, it works. But when I change `-fx-font-size` or other font-properties in the CSS stylesheet, the default font is used instead of my custom font. Is there a way to set the font size and color while maintaining my custom font? Or is it possible to set a custom font for my label in the CSS stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to be sure check your custom font is in available/loadable list by `Font.getFontNames()`.
Then check its usage by either:

```
label.setStyle(
      "-fx-font-family: MyFont;"
    + "-fx-font-size: 32;"
    + "-fx-font-style: italic;"
    + "-fx-text-fill: blue");
```

or

```
label.setFont(Font.font("MyFont", FontPosture.ITALIC, 32));
label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
```

These 2 are equivalent. Additionally you can carry out the style attributes to CSS file. Changing the font attributes other than `-fx-font-family` should not affect the font family attribute.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why it didn't work before when I tried this in a similar way in my CSS stylesheet, but maybe it's because I typed `-fx-font-family: Gill Sans MT` instead of `-fx-font-family: 'Gill Sans MT'` (name of the font between single quotes). Anyway, it seems to work now :)